# Converting from superclass to subclass

Tags: c#, object

in c# how can we convert from superclass to subclass in order to use specific method related to subclass an example is given below

```
Public class A{ 
}
Public class B:A{

MethodName;
}
```

I've tried

```
A a= new A;
(B) b=(B)(a); 
b.MethodName();
```

But it doesn't work , any suggestion?

Comment: It doesn't work because an `A` is not a `B`.  Can you give a more real-world example of why you're trying to downcast?

Comment: Let's say you have a class `car` and a subclass of `honda`.  If you have an instance of `car`, can you cast that as a `honda`?  No, because not all cars are Hondas.

Comment: Rename `A`to be `Animal ` and `B` to be `Bear`.  You can see that all Bears are Animals, but not all Animals are Bears.  Just because you have a reference to Animal, you can't make it a Bear.  It might be a Cat.

Comment: If you want to _create_ a `B` from an _existing_ `A` by copying it's properties then that is certainly possible.  Do some research on copy constructors for an example of that.

Comment: If I have the abstract concept of a car, it should be easier to get one of those abstractions to be a Honda than another fully formed car to be a Honda (assuming the abstraction could be instantiated, which is what languages like C# allow without additional keywords). Other programming languages allow this, so it's not completely unreasonable that one would desire this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert a base class to it's derived class; @PaulAbbott explained why in his comment. However, if you have an object of the base class that holds a value of the derived class, you can capture an object of the derived class using the `as` operator, to call the method:

```
        A a = new B();
        B b = (a as B); //Try to capture the value of "a" into an object of type "B"; and if you fail, return null
        if(b != null) //If "a" really holds a value of type "B"
            b.MethodName();
```

Another option is `abstract method` in an `abstract class`; but in this case, you will have to make `A` abstract (`abstract class A`).

```
    abstract class A 
    {
        public abstract void MethodName();
    }

    class B : A 
    {
        public override void MethodName()
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

and

```
        A a = new B();
        a.MethodName(); //See which derived class do I ("a") hold his value, and call the overridden method from there ("B")
```

**BUT** this will prevent you from using `A`'s constructors and will have you to override the abstract method in every derived class.